# Problems with writing to a file and searching an array

Tags: java, arrays, file, loops

Sorry for any mistakes, I tried to make a few corrections to make it easier to understand what I am doing and what I need help on. I am very new to java and this site.

I am trying to write a program that will organize the data for states (state name, state nickname, state population, state flower,and state capital) found in 5 separate files into five separate parallel arrays. The the code will ask for an input and give the user the data with the population formatted with commas. I am  also creating a method to write all information to an output file.

I am having a few issues.

I was wondering if I could get help with a few problems?

First, the file state_data.txt is blank after running the code.

Secondly, my program crashes if you input an invalid choice in the askState method instead of asking for a new input

I would appreciate any help!!

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
     *

     */

public class Project_3a {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static final int NUM_STATES = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String[] stateNames = importFile("stateNames.txt");
        String[] nicknames = importFile("nicknames.txt");
        String[] populations = importFile("population.txt");
        String[] flowers = importFile("flowers.txt");
        String[] capital = importFile("capitals.txt");
        for (int x = 0; x < NUM_STATES; x++) 
         {

         createFile(stateNames, nicknames, capital, flowers, populations);
         char getWantsToContinue = 'y'; 
         while (getWantsToContinue == 'y' || getWantsToContinue == 'Y') 
         { 
           System.out.println(stateNames); 
           int index = askState(stateNames); 
           String unformattedPopulation = populations[index]; 
           String formattedPopulation = formatPopulation(unformattedPopulation);                   
           outPut(stateNames,nicknames, capital, flowers, formattedPopulation,index);             
         }
         getWantsToContinue = again();
    }

    public static String[] importFile(String fileName) throws
            FileNotFoundException {

        String[] array = new String[NUM_STATES];

        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);


        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextLine();

        }
        return array;

    }

    public static int askState(String[] stateNames) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String state;
        int statePosition = -1;
        System.out.println("Please enter a state that you would like to search:");
        state = keyboard.nextLine();
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
                if (state.equals(stateNames[i])) {
                    statePosition = i;
                    return statePosition;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid state:");

        }
        return statePosition;
    }

    public static String formatPopulation(String population) {
        String formattedPopulations = "";
        {
            for (int i = population.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                formattedPopulations = population.charAt(i) + formattedPopulations;
                if (i % 3 == 2 && (i + 1 != population.length())) {
                    formattedPopulations = "," + formattedPopulations;
                }
            }
            return formattedPopulations;
        }

    }

    public static void createFile(String[] stateNames, String[] nicknames,
            String[] capitals, String[] flowers, String[] populations) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter stateData = new PrintWriter("state_data.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
            stateData.println(stateNames[i] + "\t" + nicknames[i] + "\t" + capitals[i]
                    + "\t" + flowers[i] + "\t" + formatPopulation(populations[i]) + "\n");
        }
        stateData.close();
    }

    public static void outPut(String[] stateNames, String[] nicknames,
            String[] capitals, String[] flowers, String formattedPopulation,
            int index) {
        System.out.println("State Name: " + stateNames[index]);
        System.out.println("Nickname: " + nicknames[index]);
        System.out.println("Capital: " + capitals[index]);
        System.out.println("Flower: " + flowers[index]);
        System.out.println("Population: " + formattedPopulation);
    }

    public static char again() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        char getWantsToContinue;
        System.out.println("Would you like to search another state?");
        System.out.println("Please enter Y for yes or N for no.");
        getWantsToContinue = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        while (getWantsToContinue != 'y' && getWantsToContinue != 'Y'
                && getWantsToContinue != 'n' && getWantsToContinue != 'N') {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid option (Yor N).");
            getWantsToContinue = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        }
        if (getWantsToContinue == 'n' || getWantsToContinue == 'N') {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }

        return getWantsToContinue;

    }
}
```

Comment: *"I would appreciate and help!!"*  We would appreciate any question!  Do you have a question?  What is your question?

Comment: My question was how do I fix my 2 issues I mentioned above.

Comment: A question should end in '?'.  For the sake of getting the attention of those people who search for a '?' in the text, and go immediately to the next post if none present, *[edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20320600/edit)* to **add them** at the appropriate point!

Comment: add a conditional statement for the user input, using a `while` loop. Ad make your code moree readable for better help

Comment: I tried to make some changes so readers can better understand what I am asking.

Comment: @user3052882 : It is really difficult to understand what you wish to achieve through the code. You should explain some more.

Comment: Okay, made some more changes. Thanks for your patience guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would just add upon the issues that I find out in your code.

(1). First issue that I found is in the function `importFile`.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextLine();

    }
```

This loop looks erroneous to me. You are trying to scan a line for 50 times from a file and each line you want it to store in an index position of string. This is absurd. 
Also, are you really sure that you have to run the loop 50 times always? (This too looks erroneous to me).

So, Of what I perceive, I think that you meant to read 50 characters from file 1 and put it into String array of size 50, which means you have to read one character at a time.

So my suggestions to clear this issue would be :

```
(a). Read one character at a time.
(b). If you are not sure about the size of each file, iterate through it till the EOF.
```

(2). Second issue I find in `createFile` method.

You are creating a new file and inserting the first character from all the files. Then the second . Then the third... Till 50th character.

What if a respective file does not have any data till 50th character. This will feed in erroneous data in your resultant file. 
This may not lead to a compile time exception but may lead to a run time exception that is undesirable.

(3). In the `main` method:

```
     for (int x = 0; x < NUM_STATES; x++) 
         {

         **createFile(stateNames, nicknames, capital, flowers, populations);**
         char getWantsToContinue = 'y'; 
         while (getWantsToContinue == 'y' || getWantsToContinue == 'Y') 
         { 
           System.out.println(stateNames); 
           int index = askState(stateNames); 
           String unformattedPopulation = populations[index]; 
           String formattedPopulation = formatPopulation(unformattedPopulation);                   
           outPut(stateNames,nicknames, capital, flowers, formattedPopulation,index);             
         }
```

This means that `createFile` method is called for 50 times. Which always creates the same "state_data.txt" file for 50 time ?? (What is this for?)

Looking for other issues. Meanwhile, start working on correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are confused in how to use `Scanner` instance to read the file. In your `importFile` method, you have assumed that there are atleast 50 lines of data and reading it using `scanner.nextLine()`. You have to check whether there is a next line and then read it otherwise, it will throw `NoSuchElementException` when there is no next line. The code should be

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
scanner.next();
}
```

or

```
  while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Similarly, in your `createFile` method are you sure that all your argument `String arrays` are of length `50`? `For` loop is always programmed to run for 50 times to create the `String` literal with assumed 50 index values (0-49) of all arrays passed to the method. This will cause `RuntimeException` when there is no index value found - `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. You need to handle this by checking for all arrays `length` should be `50` before doing this operation. Preferrably, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating the`String instance inside a`loop`. In your`askState` method, you are not having a conditional loop to re-ask for the input, when the user keys in an invalid state.

```
while(invalidState(state)){
System.out.println("Please enter input");
state = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

The other important thing is that you are invoking the `createFile` method for fifty times, which is not at all needed since you have all the various files data in array. Passing the arrays to `createFile` method once is enough and then write the logic to do the write operation of the total data into a single file

```
for (int x = 0; x < NUM_STATES; x++) 
         {

         createFile(stateNames, nicknames, capital, flowers, populations);
```

I would suggest that you have to debug your program completely to ensure that your code works in the same way you think. Hope this helps